Proof attempt for evaluating limits of a power-weighted integral
I'm trying to prove the following statement but I don't know how to proceed and explain it.
Let $ f:[0,1] \rightarrow \mathbb{R} $, a continuous function. Calculate:
$$
\lim_{n\to \infty} \int_0^1 n x^{n-1} f(x) \, dx
$$
Attempt:
For this proof, we are going to observe the behavior of $n x^{n-1}$ in three cases:
Case 1: $ x = 0 $
At $x = 0$, no matter the value of $n$, the expression $n x^{n-1}$ will always be zero:
$$
n x^{n-1} = n \cdot 0^{n-1} = 0
$$
So, the contribution to the integral from $ x = 0 $ is 0.
Case 2: $ x = 1 $
At $ x = 1 $, the expression becomes:
$$
n x^{n-1} = n \cdot 1^{n-1} = n
$$
This means that near $ x = 1 $, the function $ n x^{n-1} $ becomes very large as $ n \to \infty $.
Case 3: $ 0 < x < 1 $
In this case, for any fixed $ x \in (0,1) $, observe that:
$$
x^{n-1} \to 0 \quad \text{as} \quad n \to \infty,
$$
since $ 0 < x < 1 $ implies $ x^n $ decrease exponentially fast towards 0. Thus, for $ 0 < x < 1 $, the term $ n x^{n-1} $ becomes negligible as $ n \to \infty$.
From these observations, we can conclude that the behavior of the integral is dominated by the values of $ x $ near 1, since for $ 0 < x < 1 $, $ n x^{n-1} $ tends to 0.
Now I am stuck on how to formalize these ideas into a complete proof. I would appreciate any hints or guidance on how to proceed from here. Should I use a more rigorous argument to show that the integral converges to $ f(1) $?
Thank u all!

Perhaps you could try the substitution $y = x^{n-1}$?
